# Treeview second child node binding error

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am using asp treeview control.Its main node and child node dynamically binding is successfull.but I cannot bind the second childnode.
I think my code is not proper. pls currect my code anybody.
my code is below

```
   <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All">
                                </asp:TreeView>
 void AddNodes()
    {
        var module = context.tblModules.Where(x => x.isDelete == false && x.moduleLink_Id == 0);
        foreach (var mod in module)
        {
            int count = TreeView1.Nodes.Count;
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(mod.moduleName, mod.record_Id.ToString()));
            AddSubNodes(count, mod.record_Id);

        }
    }

    void AddSubNodes(int count, int recordId)
    {
        var child = context.tblModules.Where(x => x.moduleLink_Id == recordId);
        foreach (var x in child)
        {
            TreeView1.Nodes[count].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(x.moduleName, x.record_Id.ToString()));
            int c=TreeView1.Nodes[count].ChildNodes.Count;
            AddSecondSubNodes(count,c, x.record_Id);
        }
    }
  void AddSecondSubNodes(int node_count,int count, int recordId)
    {
         var child = context.tblModules.Where(x => x.moduleLink_Id == recordId);
         foreach (var x in child)
         {
             TreeView1.Nodes[node_count].ChildNodes[count].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(x.moduleName, x.record_Id.ToString()));
         }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get Error message? or not? check index of items also. its begin from 0 in each child nodes.

Comment: Getting error message as `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index`

Comment: still it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code :

```
AddSecondSubNodes(count-1,c-1, x.record_Id);
```